# Why are my iOS app's session lengths 30 min + in Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

More importantly, how do I fix it?

It's as if backgrounding the app doesn't end the session.

Comment: Sounds like backgrounding the app doesn't end the session. :D

Comment: it does, doesn't it? how do I fix it though?

Comment: What do you have going on in the app? Do you know of any background loading?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When your app goes into background mode it needs to tell the analytics to stop tracking.

Application Delegate would have something like:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];
}
```

In google's [Easy Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/tracking/mobile/ios/EasyTracker/Library/EasyTracker.m) example, a view controller receives notifications when app state changes. Tracking is stopped when app goes into background (Around line 400).

```
if ([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    if (self.state == EasyTrackerStateForeground) {
      // Transitioned from foreground to background. Generate the app stop
      // event, and stop the tracker.
      NSLog(@"Transitioned from foreground to background.");
      NSError *error = nil;
      if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@""
                                           action:@""
                                            label:@""
                                            value:0
                                        withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error tracking foreground event: %@", error);
      }
      // TODO(fmela): make this time period a constant.
      if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatchSynchronous:2.0]) {
        NSLog(@"Synchronous dispatch on background failed!");
      }
      [[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];
    }
    self.state = EasyTrackerStateBackground;
  }
```

Comment: Hi there, are you sure this is ending the session as GA sees it?

Comment: Sorry, hit enter instead of shift+enter. This is the rest:

I've got a test app and have turned on debug mode and am looking at the dispatch hits.

So my app flow looks like this:
I start the app and fire a page view.
I hit the home button and send the app to the background.
I tap the app icon and bring the app back into the foreground, and when I do so I fire an event.

Here are the __utma bits from my __utm.gif hits:
page view : 1.334475189.1334947296.1334956043.1334956141.13
event     : 1.334475189.1334947296.1334956141.1334956163.14

The view count is incremented here. Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: ***stopTracking*** method in ***applicationDidEnterBackground*** is not ending the session in my case, I'm using ARC in my project and I can't use the dealloc method like in the GA example. There is no other way to end the session?

Comment: I've tried ending the session in this manner, also.  No luck.  Analytics still continues the iOS session after 30 minutes of inactivity AND after 24 hours.  Very different than what the Analytics docs say (for webpages, at least).

Answer (score 0):

It says if the user has an event with in `30` mins it will treat it as the same session.  So all it means is if the user came back within `30` minutes of using your app.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/sessions

Answer (score -1):

This might help: [Updating Google Session Tracking](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/08/update-to-sessions-in-google-analytics.html)

It talks about web, but specifically mentions a 30 minute rule.

Answer (score -2):

to end the session when the app goes to background, use

```
applicationWillResignActive
```

and maybe put about:blank or something in your webview. (*assumption ;)*)

save the location and reload it in

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

or read more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Assumptions don't belong in answers -- additionally this question is regarding how to stop the tracker in an app, not a webview. Plus the user is specifically looking for the command to put in `applicationWillResignActive` to stop the tracker.